# PL/SQL - want to convert number to currency

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field **Amount** with the value **0000006472**. I need to write a query to change it to `64.72`.

What is the command I have to use. I tried to use `to_char`, `to_number`, none of them works. Can any one please give me answer to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, if `Amount` has leading `0`s, then it is stored as a string.  You can convert it to a number, divide by 100, and then format it again (if you like).

Try doing this:

```
select to_char(cast(val as float)/100, '99.99')
```

Or just leave it as a number after you have done the division.

Comment: My column Amount has all types of values like 1000.00,100.00,10.00... when trying to execute the above query is failing... how can we do so for all kinds of values

Comment: If it is failing because of the range, then just add more `9`s to the format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
SELECT '0000006472'::numeric / 100
```

This solution will also convert your value to numeric. Maybe, if you want to deal with values of this column as a numeric you should alter column to store values as numbers with

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName> ALTER COLUMN "Amount" NUMERIC(2)
```